# how can I properly configure the HorizontalScrollView and the Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have this TableRow of EditText inserted in a tablelayout, this tablelayout is inserted in one Scrollview, this Scrollview is inserted in a HorizontalScrollView. HorizontalScrollView contains, Also, an image of the background. The problem is that I can't scroll properly and display all the EditText. Can you help me?

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this); 
HSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
HSC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);
ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
VSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
values = new EditText[r][c];
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){           
tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
values[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
values[i][j].setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
tableRow.addView(values[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `Gravity.CENTER` parameters, or the scroller will scroll from the center of its content that is big enough. It's there, but you can't get it.
2. Correct various `values`

Code:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
HSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
HSC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);        
ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
VSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
// you may or may not change here and below 
// values = new EditText[15][15];
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){           
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
    tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        EditText value = new EditText(this);
        value.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |     InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        value.setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));
        value.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tableRow.addView(value);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
VSC.addView(tableLayout);
HSC.addView(VSC);
frameLayout.addView(HSC);
// ... add frameLayout
// ...
}
```

Comment: i have edited my code with your advice and i tried. Now the scroll works to the right, but not to the left horizontally, and if the number of EditText is smaller such as a TableRow with 3 rows and 3 columns the TableRow is not centered on the screen. Can you help me?

Comment: 1. Remove `Gravity.CENTER`s of both `VSC` and `tableLayout`. 2. You can set the `HSC`'s parent's gravity to `Gravity.CENTER`.

Comment: I did, but now if the number of rows and columns of the TableRow is less than 15 for example 3 the TableRow is not centered on the screen

Comment: You can wrap it within a `FrameLayout`, then `HSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));`

Comment: I tried but in this way, if the number of rows or columns of the TableRow, and for example 3, the screen is not full and the TableRow is displayed in the top to the left

Comment: But change both 15 to 3 works for me that the table shows exactly in the center of the screen

Comment: I edited my post to make more understandable the program. in the first activity  take the number of rows and columns of the TableRow (r and c) and in the second activity, where the code is in the post, I create the table EditText

Comment: Check `frameLayout`'s parent whether it's big enough.

Comment: So why not background the image to its big parent instead of `HSC`?

Comment: i solved in this way frameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna); tanks :-)